# CNN incompatible

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

My data has the following shapes:

```
 X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
    print(X_train.shape, X_test.shape, Y_train.shape, Y_test.shape)
(942, 32, 32, 1) (236, 32, 32, 1) (942, 3, 3) (236, 3, 3)
```

And whenever I try to run my CNN I get the following error:

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import Model
img_input = layers.Input(shape=(32, 32, 1))

x = layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', strides = 1, padding = 'same')(img_input)
x = layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', strides = 2)(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu', strides = 2)(x)
x = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2)(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(3, 3, activation='linear', strides = 2)(x)


output = layers.Flatten()(x)

model = Model(img_input, output)
model.summary()

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer= 'adam', metrics=['mse'])

history = model.fit(X_train,Y_train,validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), epochs = 100,verbose=1)
```

Error:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [32,3] vs. [32,3,3]
     [[node BroadcastGradientArgs_2 (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1751) ]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_7567]

Function call stack:
distributed_function
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't handle the dimensionality inside your network properly. Firstly expand the dimension of your y in order to get them in this format (n_sample, 3, 3, 1). At this point adjust the network (I remove flatten and max pooling and adjust the last conv output)

```
# create dummy data
n_sample = 10
X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (n_sample, 32, 32, 1))
y = np.random.uniform(0,1, (n_sample, 3, 3))

# expand y dim
y = y[...,np.newaxis]
print(X.shape, y.shape)

img_input = Input(shape=(32, 32, 1))

x = Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', strides = 1, padding = 'same')(img_input)
x = Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', strides = 2)(x)
x = Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu', strides = 2)(x)
x = Conv2D(1, (3,3), activation='linear', strides = 2)(x)

model = Model(img_input, x)
model.summary()

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer= 'adam', metrics=['mse'])
model.fit(X,y, epochs=3)
```

Comment: I expanded it as you described: (942, 32, 32, 1) (236, 32, 32, 1) (942, 3, 3, 1) (236, 3, 3, 1)

but I get the following: ValueError: A target array with shape (942, 3, 3, 1) was passed for an output of shape (None, 1) while using as loss `mean_squared_error`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.

Comment: my target shape is (None,3,3,1) as u can check in the model summary and not (None,1). Try to use the same model I provide. here the running notebook without errors https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1E81__wDsqICifk0qpnMohlSOZVsc6N9l?usp=sharing don't forget to upvote and accept it as answer ;-)

Comment: worked, thank you! 
one last question: what change should I apply when I wanted to feed in training set with (n_sample,12,12,1) ?

Comment: obviously your input must be (n_sample,12,12,1) and then you have to play with padding, strides and pooling (the latest if necessary) in order to match the dimensionality

Comment: what exactly does playing with padding etc. mean?

Comment: padding='valid' and 'same' influence the dimensionality in a different way https://machinelearningmastery.com/padding-and-stride-for-convolutional-neural-networks/